# programmatically start the game engine?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, command-line

I have this piece of code that's meant to start the game engine (and it does so if I just run this on the default screen)...I have a script that generates an environment with planes, spheres, etc. and appended this piece of code on the bottom but I'm getting a poll() context error...I'm in 3d view by default and the below thing should make it run in the game engine...any way to fix this so it actually works?

```
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'BLENDER_GAME'
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override['area'] = area
        bpy.ops.view3d.game_start()
        break
```

Comment: can you post the error message that is in the console?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are in edit mode. The bge will only start in object mode.

Adding this line `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')` to your script will alleviate that issue.

Your edited code:

```
import bpy

bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'BLENDER_GAME'

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override['area'] = area
        bpy.ops.view3d.game_start()
        break
```

Comment: hm, I'm still getting a poll() context error...

full error message: RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3d.game_start.poll() failed, context is incorrect